# How do I get a CDMA USB Modem ZTE AC682 modem working?

Tags: network-manager, usb-modem, modem-manager, zte

How to make my usb modem ZTE ac682 work instanly, i mean when i put the modem my system (ubuntu 11.10) can recognize my modem automatically??? do anyone have a workaround?

Comment: I think its a problem that is faced from Ubuntu 11.10. In the previous versions the switching would only require a `sudo eject /dev/sr1` command. But from 11.10 and later, the `eject` command cannot eject the 19d2:ffde to 19d2:ffdd. So far, [I have found](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/zd1211rw/Driverless) that this is due to the Linux version 2.6.19 or above that it acts that way. So far I was unable to eject the device. It seems that it shows an old sg driver message and nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the modem will be detected when you plugged in. You may see like the screenshot shows under network icon.

[image]

The configuration is easy just click on the detected modem and follow the instruction.

To configure you CDMA using another way check this answer: [How do i configure universal USB modems in linux (e.g. iBall 3.5G Connect)](https://askubuntu.com/a/95934/9701)

Comment: thanks for respond,
no, i cant do that easily...
i must configure the modem first, and do this step by step guide
 
http://citycellmodemtroubleshoot.blogspot.com/2011/02/installation-of-zte-ac682-modem-in.html

my question is, is there a way to make this usb modem can be recognize automatically???
sorry my english :D

Answer (score 0):

often one needs to needs the modem to switch from being a mass storage device (usually a read only memory that shares the windows install driver) to pop up as a 3g modem

by default when Ubuntu sees the ID of your device, it will recognize it and switch it for you. If it doesn't recognize it then its probably still to new for the distribution that you are using.

Try installing usb mode switch from their homepage and do the switch manually with their program.

http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/

once the modem has been successfully switched. It will pop up as a 3g modem and you can continue through the ordinary "ubuntu way" of connecting to the internet through 3g.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to eject that device first , because it shows as a storage drive . check lsusb if there product id and vendor is 19d2:ffde then after eject it will change to 19d2:ffdd . Then you can connect from normal modem way .

Answer (score 0):

I also have a ZTE modem, but It gets automatically detected, But this might take up to 5min some times, so

- Have you tried waiting?
- Are you able to connect to internet through this modem at all? If you are able to, How are you connecting?

Any way If you follow the configuration procedure and add the username/password you should be able to connect with out any trouble.