# How to configure iBall airway 3G usb modem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, broadband

I bought new **iball Airway 21MP 3G modem** last month. But Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't detect my device. It is perfectly working in windows with installed driver. I'm not getting an option to "Enable mobile broadband" in top panel. but lsusb list the device

> root@eldho-Latitude-E6410:~# lsusb
>   Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1782:0003 Spreadtrum Communications Inc. -------->>>>
>   root@eldho-Latitude-E6410:~#

As per the link " [How do I get an iball 3.5G modem working on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384562/how-do-i-get-an-iball-3-5g-modem-working-on-ubuntu)"
I captured the USB sniffs to find the switch event for a working product ID and vendor ID.
But it shows the same ID in that too.

Please help....!!!!

Comment: messages while plugging the device
usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1782, idProduct=0003
usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-1.2: Product: USB Modem
usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Spreadtrum
usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
usbcore: deregistering interface driver usb-storage---->>>
lctserial: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout--->>

Comment: I tried my maximum to get this particular modem (1782:0003 Spreadtrum Communications Inc.) working in Ubuntu. They providing  a mobile partner like software and it is working fine, even it automatically starting when I plug in the device. But it failed to detect the device. Somehow onece the network manager shows the modem in list, but I was unable to connect it. iBall dongles sucks both in windows and linux, do not buy it. I have successfully connected all other modems in Ubuntu using various methods (wvdial+gnom-ppp, sakis3g etc..).

Comment: My suggestion is to ask the seller of this modem to replace with another one. In my  experience 3G modems with android support usually work with Ubuntu without any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

**Below mentioned methode will only work with iBall Airway 7.2 18 (lsusb will show it as a huwawei modem)**

**iBall Airway or similar Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem 3G data cards connecting in Ubuntu.**

[image: iBall Airway 7.2 18]

Using **WvDial as backend** and **Gnome-PPP as frontend**

WvDial is a Point-to-Point Protocol dialer: it dials a modem and starts pppd in order to connect to the Internet.

First install WvDial

```
sudo apt-get install wvdial
```

Then Gnome-ppp

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp
```

Finally we need to add add WvDial to give regular users the ability to use wvdial to dial a ppp connection.

**Using a dialout group**

Set up a group called dialout (call the group as prefered) and give members of this group permission to run wvdial as root.

First create the group and add the users to it:

```
sudo groupadd dialout

sudo gpasswd -a username dialout
```

Note: You need to logout and log back in for the current user's group list to be updated.

Then set the group and adjust the permissions on wvdial:

```
sudo chgrp dialout /usr/bin/wvdial

sudo chmod u+s,o= /usr/bin/wvdial
```

The files should have the following permissions:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/wvdial

-rwsr-x---  1 root dialout 114368 2005-12-07 19:21 /usr/bin/wvdial
```

Now plugin your iball Airway device and wait for 15 seconds, then open gnome-ppp from unity dash board 
[image: Gnome PPP Icon]
and click setup.

[image]

Follow the screen shots to configure Gnome-ppp.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

System tray icon of Gnome PPP, after success full connection.

[image]

Disclosure : http://angamaly.lug.org.in member

References : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wvdial