# iball 3.5G not working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, usb-modem

My problem is with installing i ball 3.5G wireless connect modem in ubuntu 16.04. I referred to the following answer  on the site `https://askubuntu.com/questions/384562/how-do-i-get-an-iball-3-5g-modem-working-on-ubuntu`but I could only get the Airtel-connect option visible in the menu. I'm still not able to connect. I tried the edit connections option still it's the same. I'm a newbie to Linux so can someone help me out?
PS:I don't have any other means to connect to net so I'm unable to install wvdial or any other thing for that sort

Answer (score 0):

wvdial seems to be something you can try. Firstly, did you check the details about the modem? open a terminal and post the output of lsusb. Also, I can hardly understand the scenario where you mention Airtel connection is listed/visible from the menu? Beforehand, open a terminal and run tail -f /var/log/kern.log in Ubuntu 17.10 or tail -f /var/log/messages in 16.04 and try to connect using the network-manager dialer (click on airtel). Post the result.
These links may be interesting:
http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1513&view=previous
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_3G_Modem